# Techniques for fitting multi language labels on forms

Tags: ui, forms

I am building a multi language website on ExtJS, where I have covered all the technical aspects of the multi language aspect.

How would deal with different string lengths? Lets say I design a 160px space for an specific label. That label is 120px long on Spanish, so everything ok with that; but that same label is 200px on Finnish; what would you do? trim that string? expand the original 160px space? What if we are talking about a form with several columns?

Comment: I would like to see a more authoritative answer on this, but as a start: http://www.w3.org/International/articles/article-text-size.en (and the [linked article](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/globalization/guidelines/a3.html)). Additionally I've seen some localization platforms provide the ability for not just text but also whole UI components to be swapped out on localization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no catch-all solution. The first step is to switch to a different unit. `px` is useless for text, because some users might have set a **minimum font size** in their browsers. The only way to adapt your layout to that is to use `em` for `width` and `height`.

And string *length* is not the only problem. Line height can be an issue too. Many non-Latin scripts [need more vertical space](http://www.w3.org/International/articles/article-text-size.en).

You cannot resolve this just with code. You have to *talk* with the translators, and every translation must be tested visually.

I am working on a translation software with ten thousands of users. I talk with translators and developers every day, and I have never seen a layout that fits for all languages from the start. :)

BTW, I think this question would fit better on [ux.stackexchange.com](https://ux.stackexchange.com/).